# vaultQuery Exceeds Default Page Size

Tags: corda

I have been running some load tests on my simple CordApp and now when I do a vault query to check on the list of transactions, I get an exception in the logs: net.corda.core.node.services.VaultQueryException: Please specify a `PageSpecification` as there are more results [201] than the default page size [200]. There doesn't seem to be an option to pass a parameter for paging. Do I need to filter the results? That wouldn't affect the reason for the exception. What is the recommended practice?

Answer (score 0):

Per documented here [link](https://docs.corda.net/head/api-vault-query.html#pagination)

Max Page Size

```
val pagingSpec = PageSpecification(DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM, MAX_PAGE_SIZE)
val criteria = VaultQueryCriteria(status = Vault.StateStatus.ALL)
val results = vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(criteria, paging = pagingSpec)
```

Looping through each page.

```
var pageNumber = DEFAULT_PAGE_NUM
val states = mutableListOf<StateAndRef<ContractState>>()
do {
    val pageSpec = PageSpecification(pageNumber = pageNumber, pageSize = pageSize)
    val results = vaultService.queryBy<ContractState>(VaultQueryCriteria(), pageSpec)
    states.addAll(results.states)
    pageNumber++
} while ((pageSpec.pageSize * (pageNumber - 1)) <= results.totalStatesAvailable)
```